# How can I call a function from another component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to call a function from a different component but when I console.log('hi') it appear but it didn't call the `messageContext`.

Here is my follwing code from `Invitees.js`:

```
  const [showPreview, setShowPreview] = useState(false);

  const toggleUserPreview = () => {
    setShowPreview(!showPreview);
  };
      {showPreview && (
        <ResultsWrappers togglePreview={toggleUserPreview}>
          <UserPreview
            userInfo={applicant}
            skillStr={applicant.Skills}
            togglePreview={toggleUserPreview}
          />
        </ResultsWrappers>
      )}
```

Here is the component have the function I want to call `UserPreview.js`:

```
import { useMessageContextProvider } from "../context/MessageContext";
const UserPreview = ({ userInfo, skillStr, togglePreview }) => {
 const messageContextProvider = useMessageContextProvider();
  const messageUser = () => {
    togglePreview();
    messageContextProvider.updateActiveUserToMessage(userInfo);
    console.log('hi');
  };
...
```

};

Here is my messageContext:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
const messageContext = createContext();
export const MessageContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [activeUserToMessage, setActiveUserToMessage] = useState({});
  const [isOpenMobileChat, toggleMobileChat] = useState(false);
  const updateActiveUserToMessage = (user) => {
    setActiveUserToMessage(user);
  };
  return (
    <messageContext.Provider
      value={{
        updateActiveUserToMessage,
        activeUserToMessage,
        isOpenMobileChat,
        toggleMobileChat,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </messageContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const useMessageContextProvider = () => {
  return useContext(messageContext);
};
```

When the `messageContext` called it should open the chatbox like this:

[image]

Comment: How do you know `updateActiveUserToMessage` wasn't called? I see no way for it not to be called from the provided snippet. What debugging have you done?

Comment: I just added more details into my question!

Comment: What is the chatbox? What opens the chatbox? Your question seems to be missing context. Please try to update it to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The code you showing is not enough to say it for 100%, but it seems like `toggleUserPreview` - function called twice, so it reverted to original boolean value.

One time as `<ResultsWrappers togglePreview={toggleUserPreview}/>`

and second time as `<UserPreview togglePreview={toggleUserPreview}/>`.